# Close a child form and open another form on click of a button from user control in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Platform: C#.net

Hi, I am trying to close a child form and open a new child form which is loaded in an MDI parent form on click of a button in User control which is loaded in the MDI parent... Any suggestion please?

Comment: There is an MDI form with user control and button. When you click this button you want to close currently opened child form and open a new one. The only question left is - what problem do you have?

Comment: No the problem is the button is created in a user control and using that button i want to close the child form and open another child form ... Hope now i am clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use control should expose nthe buttons Click event, whiuch the containing form can subscribe to. Then when the containing form receives this event it can go off and do what it wants to.